Arduino controlling relays, on PCB (to check)
This is my first PCB.
Does it seems good to you?
If you look for the schematics, here it is

In the box is going to look like this:

Thank you :)
Edit:
Here the schematics:


Good as in esthetically? Or in what sense?

I recommend a safety resistor between battery and RTC (e.g. 1kohm) for people, who insert the battery in reverse direction.

If it wasn’t clear when people pointed it in your schematic review recently, with the two sides of most optocouplers bridged together, they are now useless. Is this a two-sided board with no inner layers? If yes, your ground plane is very compromised. Try to layout as much as possible on top layer and only short bridges on bottom. You can also pour ground on both layers and switch them together wherever you have free area on both sides.

I know, I'm going to replace them with 2N7000, (instead on the optocoupler PC817).
I'll update the schematics.
